# ElasticSearch terms aggregation only works if I specify the field with a script

Tags: elasticsearch

The following aggregation returns buckets like I'd expect:

```
{
  "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "my_agg": {
           "terms": {
           "script": {
              "inline": "arrayField.innerArrayField.property"
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

This aggregation, which seems like it should return the same set of buckets, returns none:

```
{
  "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "my_agg": {
          "terms": {        
              "field": "arrayField.innerArrayField.property"        
          }
        }
      }
```

}

Relevant portions of the type mapping:

```
"arrayField": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "innerArrayField": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "property": {
                "type": "string"
              }

}}
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping type is `nested`, so you should also use the [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) first. Scripting is not accessing the nested documents stored in ES, but is dynamically extracting data from the JSON source, which is slow as it must be done per hit.